# Asynchronous protobuf serialization

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

A limitation of the protobuf-net implementation is that it calls the underlying streams synchronously. By not offering an asynchronous API e.g. BeginSerialize/EndSerialize or a TPL equivalent, we are forced to tie up a thread waiting for synchronous stream I/O.

Is there any plan to offer asynchronous methods in protobuf-net, or alternatively, any creative ways around this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that isn't currently supported and would be a **lot** of work.

My suggestion would be: buffer data yourself using the async APIs, and then *when* you have the data, use something like a `MemoryStream` to deserialize...

In my defence, I'm not aware of any *other* serializer that offers an async API here. In particular, when talking about slow/async streams, that *usually* means "network": and you usually have the issue of "framing" to consider there; protobuf-net won't know your framing requirements...

Comment: Is there any generic buffered stream that blocks on async? I'm currently using a MemoryStream approach but I want to partially deserialize the header of the file (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342318/deserialize-part-of-a-binary-file) and I have no way to know how many bytes I need to retrieve Async, only the deserializer knows.

Comment: @tozevv sync-over-async? that *can* be fairly dangerous, to be honest. What is the underlying data source here? What async source is providing the data? A sync-over-async stream could probably be *written* easily enough

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with Writing. I'm reading from a file with a header and a body. If I know the size of the header is trivial to read the header (ReadAsync) first and only if the header meets a certain condition read the rest of the body also Async. Both the header and contents are being serialized using your excellent (thanks for that) implementation of protocol buffers.

Comment: @tozevv actuall, the implementation is designed to not over-read without good reason, so you should be able to trust the max-length passed into `Read`; however, another option is to parse the start of the message manually (there are utilities for reading the various parts). Again, hard to be specific without context.

Comment: Added a detailed question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268442/partial-and-asynchronous-deserialization-c-sharp-with-protobuf-net

Comment: I've submitted this as a feature request on protobuf-net issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=444 As can be seen from the proposal, it's not hard to do at all.

Answer (score 3):

I am using protobuff over the network. While the following solution doesn't guarantee it wont block, it does make life far better:

```
byte[] emptyByteArray = new Byte[0];
await stream.ReadAsync(emptyByteArray, 0, 0);
TaskData d = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TaskData>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
```

Because we make sure there is actual data on the stream before we start to deserialize, it will only end up blocking when the stream contains a partial message.

Edit: And we can use a similar trick for serialization:

```
MemoryStream mstm = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(mstm, data, PrefixStyle.Base128);
await stream.WriteAsync(mstm.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mstm.Position);
```

As a bonus, this one does guarantee to never block.

Answer (score 2):

You can await `Task.Run` that will run the synchronous code in the thread pool. It's not the most efficient solution, but it's better than blocking. You can even submit your own `CancellationToken` to `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(
    stream, data, PrefixStyle.Base128), cancellationToken);
```

Alternatively, you can use a fairly simple helper method [ripped from my JuiceStream library](https://bitbucket.org/robertvazan/juicestream/src/tip/JuiceStream/ProtobufEx.cs) that I have submitted as part of [async feature request to protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=444):

```
await ProtobufEx.SerializeWithLengthPrefixAsync(
    stream, data, PrefixStyle.Base128, cancellationToken);
await ProtobufEx.DeserializeWithLengthPrefixAsync<MyType>(
    stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Although not the most ideal approach, its a good alternative.